# How to use selenium to upload file to AWS S3 via the web console

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, amazon-s3

Normally, if you're uploading a file to S3 using the web console, from [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9hgg.png)
you click the 'Add files' button.  This opens a dialog that let you select the file(s) you want to upload, which results a page like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzJjt.png).

Suppose you cannot use boto3. Is there a way to do this using selenium (python-selenium)?  Is there an element that you can select that let you send file paths to the above page?

There does not seem to be an 'input' element on the page to allow sending file paths to it.

Comment: I'm interested in the reason why you cannot use boto3.

Comment: i think it's because of the presence of a network proxy, as `urllib`, `requests` etc. also do not work.